# Shortest null check in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, null

Is there a shorter way to write this in **c#**:

```
if(myobject!=null){

}
```

In **JavaScript** we can do this:

```
if(myobject){

}
```

**Disclaimer:** I know this will match 'true' as well in JavaScript. This would only be used on variables that should be a specific type of object.

I found some similar questions, but they're asking slightly different things:

[C# Shortest Way to Check for Null and Assign Another Value if Not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120557/c-sharp-shortest-way-to-check-for-null-and-assign-another-value-if-not)

[Best and fastest way to check if an object is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408104/best-and-fastest-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-null)

[How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)

Comment: You can do a lot of things in JavaScript that are inadvisable and which C# simply prohibits. That's one of them (there's already plenty of discussion on the web as to _why_ that's inadvisable, so I won't belabor that point).

Comment: you can write your own ifNull() function and even make it shorter by calling it ifN()..

Comment: Why the downvote..? It's a legitimate question isn't it..?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can obtain *the same syntax* in C# via `operator`:

```
  public class MyClass {
    ...
    // True if instance is not null, false otherwise
    public static implicit operator Boolean(MyClass value) {
      return !Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value);  
    }   
  }


....

  MyClass myobject = new MyClass();
  ...
  if (myobject) { // <- Same as in JavaScript
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Although this is the only way to achieve a shorter `null` check IMHO, this works only for your own classes, unfortunately.

Comment: Works like a charm! Just a note, I had to make it static too.. eg. public static implicit operator ...

Comment: @fero You could write an `IsNull(this object o)` extension method and then use it as `if (someObject.IsNull())`. This would work for any object. Question is whether it is that much shorter...

Answer (score 8):

C# language philosophy is quite different than that of JavaScript. C# usually forces you to be more explicit about somethings in order to prevent some common programming errors (and I'm sure this also helps simplify the compiler design & test).

If C# had allowed such an implicit conversion to boolean, you are much more likely to run into programming errors like this:

```
if(myobject = otherObject)
{
   ...
}
```

where you've made an *assignment* instead of an *equality check*. Normally C# prevents such mistakes (so although Dmitry's answer is clever, I'd advise against it).

Comment: You are correct. Tested this as well and it does slip through.

Answer (score 2):

used ?? Operator  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator

```
 var myobject = notNullValue ?? nullValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Throw an `ArgumentNullException` e.g. to check method parameters, there is a handy one-liner to do this:

```
_ = x ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));
```

Here, we try to assign the parameter to the discard `_` operator. The `??`-operator performs a nullcheck. If the variable is null, the exception is thrown.

In Visual Studio you can add a custom snippet to bind this line to the shortcut `arg0`. You only need to type `arg0`, double press the TAB key, and to type the parameter name. Implementing a null check then only takes 2 seconds.

Here is the snippet. To import it into Visual Studio, please use this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
        <Title>Argument null check for parameters</Title>
        <Shortcut>arg0</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Code Language="CSharp">
            <![CDATA[_= $param$ ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof($param$));]]>
        </Code>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>param</ID>
                <ToolTip>Name of the parameter.</ToolTip>
                <Default>x</Default>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use object class static method ReferenceEquals method to find out if the refrence is null or not

```
  MyClass1 obj = new MyClass1();
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj,null))
        {
            Console.Write("obj ref is null");
        }
```

Comment: `object.ReferenceEquals(obj,null)` is not shorter than `obj == null`. In fact, I'd argue it's quite a bit longer.